# What was the Arbiter's name originally in Halo?

Tags: halo-series

I know that the Arbiter wasn't originally planned to be called the Arbiter and that the developers had other names planned for him.

What were those names and why was it eventually decided to use "Arbiter"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Arbiter was originally meant to be called the "Dervish". The name was changed because it might create an unintended parallel between the game and the real-life conflict between the Western World and the Middle East.

[image: Halo Arbiter (Dervish)]

In the Spanish version of Halo 2 and Halo 3, the Arbiter is called "Inquisidor". This is because the false cognate "árbitro" means "umpire" instead of "Arbiter".

Comment: While the rest of the answer seems plausible, where do you get "Larry"?

Comment: @Wondercricket 30sec into this video https://youtu.be/QVVxTH5w5UI from Rocket Sloth

Comment: @Wondercricket Okay. I did lots of research and could not find "Larry" anywhere. Turns out that "Larry" was an April Fool's joke in that video :D

Comment: Please add the source of the image. Is is from a storyboard of the first game?

Comment: I don't think "árbitro" is a false cognate? It does have the same origin, it's just used in a somewhat different way...

Comment: @psmears: In that case, I think they're [false friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) (i.e., similar-looking, but with different meanings – and may or may not be etymologically related) but not [false cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate) (i.e., similar-looking but not etymologically related)

Comment: @V2Blast: Yeah I agree that's a more accurate term :)

Answer (score 2):

The Arbiter's original name is [Thel 'Vadam](https://www.halopedia.org/Thel_%27Vadam), Arbiter is a title/role given by the Prophets and typically sent on suicidal missions for the covenant to die and become a "martyr" for the Great Journey.